# Regex expresion that should select matching text but escape everything between ><

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a lot of files where i have something similar

`<span translate>textTo.translate</span>`

What need to look like is

`<span>{{ $t("textTo.translate") }}</span>`

What i do now is find all occurrences of `span translate>` and `replace all` with `span>{{ $t("` and then go thru file and finish step by step

Is there any regex that i could use in replace all to achieve this?

What i managed to do is to select all `(span translate>)[^<>]+(?=<)` but i cannot find replacement regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

**Find**: `<span\s+translate>([^<>]+)<`
**Replace**: `<span>{{ $t("$1") }}<`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yWnFSR/1).

*Details*:

- `<span\s+translate>` - a `<span` string, one or more whitespaces and then a `translate>` string
- `([^<>]+)` - Group 1 (`$1` refers to this group value): one or more chars other than `<` and `>`
- `<` - a `<` char

The replacement is `<span>{{ $t("` + Group 1 value + `") }}<` text.

See the demo:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, thats it. Do you have idea why doesn't work in InteliJ?

Comment: @ZeljkoMarinkovic In theory, it must work there, too, since the syntax of the current expression is simple and Intellij also uses `$1` backreference syntax. Make sure you select the right options, e.g. enable the regex search if it is not selected yet.

Comment: for some reason it wont work, but thanks for your help :)

Comment: just to correct myself i need to escape $ sign in replacement string in order to work in IntelliJ.

so replacement string need to look like:
`span>{{ /$t("$1") }}<`

Answer (score 0):

nvm, found answer <strike>but for some reason works only in VSCode while fails in PHPStorm</strike>.

**Find** regex: `span translate>([^<>]+(?=))<`

**Replace** regex: `span>{{ \$t("$1") }}<`